# More information about a closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions

I was doing some research via google on a good way to get started with iOS game programming when I came across a closed question that had some of the answers I was looking for.  This question was closed, and wouldn't allow me to reply to the users asking it.  (At least, I believe this was the reason I could not reply)  However I would really like to be able to ask those users for more information about the software(s) they had recommended.

My question then is this:
If the reason that I cannot reply is indeed that the question was closed (and not for some other reason that I am unaware of due to my lack of experience on StackOverflow) then is there a way to vote to re-open the question somehow?  OR  Is there another way to contact the aforementioned users in another way.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can you link to the question?

Comment: Regardless of the actual question you refer to; [you need 50 reputation to leave comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (which you can do on closed questions)

Comment: Thanks for the snappy reply.  I was unaware that I needed 50 reputation to leave comments.  Thanks for the information.  Is there a part of the site somewhere that explains how all of those sorts of rules work?

Comment: Here is the question I was looking at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224479/what-is-required-to-develop-iphone-games

Comment: There is the main [HELP](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section which is pretty in depth. Or there is the [ABOUT](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page which is more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the question was probably closed because it's asking for recommendations, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

As such, it probably will not be reopened.  If the question is only closed and not locked, then the only reason you wouldn't be able to comment on it is that you don't have enough reputation yet. You need 50 reputation to comment on other people's posts.

You can see what privileges are unlocked at what reputation levels on the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page.  Note that you can cast close and reopen votes when you reach 3000 reputation.

Comment: Is there a StackExchange where asking for recommendations (or similar) is on topic?

Comment: @TheDoctor Not a Stack Exchange site, but there is [Slant](http://www.slant.co/).